# Ubuntu 18.04.4 with nvidia-driver-440 freezing screen

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

So I just had quite often random freezing screens with nvidia-driver-440 with ubuntu desktop environment and dkm3 or sddm manager. How should I solve this? It's very disturbing as I can't even get log for this because of the freezing screen.

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e81 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 3183
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I use CUDA 10.2 so only nvidia 440+ can be used... not that I don't want the long-term driver.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done editing... what does it look like? Problems with `nouveau`? Should I blacklist it?

Comment: There is no need to blacklist nouveau. It can only make it worse.

Comment: @Pilot6 so... no solution for now?

Comment: What is behind these `***` is the Nvidia model a secret?

Comment: @Pilot6 just my device number, not that much of a secret... the point is, rn my ubuntu freezes after average 20 minutes from starting up

Comment: We need to check that you installed the correct driver for your device, but you keep it in secret ))

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry, revised. CUDA 10.2 only allows 440+ driver

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading this answer: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

I had the same problem for weeks. Unfortunately, the only way to use Ubuntu for me was to change from the Nvidia driver to Intel.
You can do it with:
`sudo prime-select intel`

Comment: I know, but I need CUDA...

Comment: you can try: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-driver-440`

Comment: I already added the ppa some time ago, but the issue still appeared